# How to read regular expression settings from a configuration file written in xml?

Tags: python, regex, xml

I have a regular expression in my settings written in XML.
Is there a way to read the settings as a regular expression in python?

For example, there's are websites which the titles are partially the same.
I want to write a code that considers these titles as the same.

- Title 1: Shanghai - Google Maps
- Title 2: Tokyo - Google Maps

→ Consider these titles as "Google Maps"

Example code is written below:

```xml
<config>
    <title>(.*)Google Maps</title>
</config>
```

If I just read this xml file with `xml.etree.ElementTree` library, it just read the settings as a string.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to load a regex from an xml file?

```py
import re
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring("<config> <title>(.*)Google Maps</title> </config>")
conds = {c.tag: re.compile(c.text) for c in root.getchildren()}
# example
conds['title'].match("Tokyo - Google Maps")
```

but I'm not sure I have correctly understood your question.

Comment: thank you! that's what I wanted to do. and it worked!